# How to store data with key stretching in mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, encryption, aes, pbkdf2

I need to store data in mysql database using aes_encrypt() function.

The key in the case of above mentioned function is padded with zero when its length is less than 16 bytes.

My question is:
How can I perform a key stretching with something like PBKDF2 in mysql to enhance the strength of weak keys.

Also I would like to know that if I use a hex value directly from a function like `SHA2('Key', 512)` as my key for the aes_encrypt() function, will it reduce the strength of the key because there will only be 16 characters in the character set every time a key is generated.

Comment: Do you really want to do this in SQL? Why don't you do this in the application layer where there is almost certainly easy support for PBKDF2?

Comment: @ArtjomB. actually its an old project where the owner of the project doesn't wants to modify the architecture, so I am left with no other option than doing this.